# How can I save a plot as pdf file but it has to look like the result of plt.show()?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I didn't know how to formulate my question, you will understand a lot better with some screenshots.

I'm currently saving my figure with:

```
plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The result file looks like this:

[image: screenshot of my pdf file]

Right after I call the `savefig` function, I call `plt.show()` and here is what i want in the pdf file :

[image: what i'm looking for]

As you can see there's some significant differences between the two pictures, and I don't know why.

Comment: the first screen just looks mushed vertically and without legends. what does documentation for plt.savefig() have for options?

Comment: Ask me anything if you're looking for more informations

Comment: i just did ask you :) what documentation did you find fo rhthe plt.savefig() function? did you look in the documentation first?

Comment: @melgart it has legend, also, it is very weird because every axes remain the same, but the dimensions have changed. I'll look up to savefig

Comment: @melgart, the only relevant parameter of the `savefig()` function is `orientation` but i tried it and it didn't do anything

Comment: It  is not an orientation problem. I think it is a size problem. Try changing the figure **figsize** parameter

Comment: @Jalo the problem is that I still need to see the figure as i'm currently seeing it with `plt.show()`, but I also need to save it cause some coworkers need to be able to rewatch the figure without relaunching the whole program.

Comment: Try adding this line before savefig: plt.figure(figsize=(18,6))  If it works, adjust the size changing the numbers

Comment: The instruction changes depending of your code, but you should post it if you want a complete answer

Comment: @Jalo wow i'm so sorry, i didn't know figsize was doing that, thanks a lot mate, it actually worked.

Comment: i'm working on a confidential project, i'm not allowed to post any sample of code sorry, but you helped me a lot there, I had set figsize to (100,50) that's why dimensions were totally random, thanks again

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a size problem, as the savefig instruction is saving it with a non suitable shape. In order to get a proper size, you have to set the figsize parameter to the one that fits your plot:

```
width = 18
height = 6
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```